# Component affected by other component's props?

Tags: reactjs

Very strange, I have this situation:

```
<Grid className="App">
    <GridRow columns={1}>
      <GridColumn>
        <StatsHeader graphData={this.state.graphData} />
      </GridColumn>
    </GridRow>
    <GridRow columns={2}>
      <GridColumn>
        <LineChart graphData={this.state.graphData != null ? this.computeDiffs(this.state.graphData) : null} />
      </GridColumn>
      <GridColumn>
        <BarChart graphData={this.state.graphData} />
      </GridColumn>
    </GridRow>
  </Grid>
```

as you can see I have linechart and barchart using te same data.

Now, if inside LineChart I do:

```
let data = this.props.graphData;
let last20 = data.splice(-20);
```

The second graph breaks as it cannot find some values.
How come?It is like the props of the first one influence the second one.

Comment: @keikai no copy is being made, shallow or otherwise. even if an online example reproducing the problem is useful in general, here the problem is easy to identify without it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array` assign/copies through reference by default, that means if you assign an array to a new variable and change that variables value, the original array will also be changed:

```
var arr1 = [1, 2]
var arr2 = arr1

arr2[0] = 2

console.log(arr1)
[2, 2]
```

There are several ways to copy the array by just it's value:

You can do `slice`

```
var arr1 = [1, 2]
var arr2 = arr1.slice(0)

arr2[0] = 2

console.log(arr1)
[1, 2]
```

So in your case, you can copy the value first:

```
let data = this.props.graphData.slice(0);
let last20 = data.splice(-20);
```

You can see more info [here](https://www.dyn-web.com/javascript/arrays/value-vs-reference.php)

Comment: very confusing indeed but..copying it with slice did the trick :)

Comment: isn't there some more refined method to pass data as a prop and be sure that it can't be modified?

Comment: @Phate you can use [immutable js](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/) or [Object.freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) or another language compiled to JS, like [Reason ML](https://reasonml.github.io/)

Answer (score 0):

Assignment operation in JS does not do any copying whatsoever, never.

[splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) is a mutable operation - it will mutate the only array that is accessible through all variables pointing to this 1 array as well as return a new array.

Using [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) will not modify the original array, only returns a new one:

```
let last20 = data.slice(-20)
```

---

I recommend https://overreacted.io/what-is-javascript-made-of/ for a good mental model of what is a "value", "variable" and "assignment".

Comment: Still...it does

Comment: in `a = []; b = a` there is only 1 Array object, no copy whatsoever, 2 variables pointing to the same object...